# Eclipse Xtext v2.10 - Keywords Characters matching issue

Tags: eclipse, keyword, xtext, mismatch

I want parse a Windows ".ini" file using Eclipse Xtext.

Below is the sample "ini" file contents

```
//-----------> Section 1
// "Routing" is a standard section
//key1 & key2 are any Alphanumeric name
[Routing]
key1=value1@value2...
key2=value1@value2...

// "Rest" is a non standard section name, Could be any name like mentioned below "Rosy"/"Rousy"   

//-----------> Section 2
//KEY1 & KEY2 are some standard key parameters required in project
[Rest]          // =======>> Works fine without error          
KEY1=Value1
KEY2=Value2

//-----------> Section 3
//KEY1 & KEY2 are some standard key parameters required in project
[Rosy]          // =======>> Throws an error "mismatched character 's', expecting 'u'"
KEY1=Value3
KEY2=Value4

//-----------> Section 4
//KEY1 & KEY2 are some standard key parameters required in project
[Rousy]          // =======>> Throws an error "mismatched character 's', expecting 't'"
KEY1=Value5
KEY2=Value6
```

Following is the Grammar,

```
terminal ALPHA :('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
terminal NUM:('0'..'9')+;

// -----------Data type rules used for INI file parsing ----------------------
SECTION:'['(ALPHA|NUM|'_')*']';

KEY : (ALPHA|NUM|'{'|'|') (ALPHA|NUM|'_'|'{'|'}'|'|'|','|'%')* ;

VALUE: ('=')? (ALPHA|NUM|'_'|'='|','|'|'|'['|']'|'('|')'|'{'|'}'|'<'|'>'|'+'|'-'|'@')+;

ROUTING_SECT_KW:
    '['('Routing')']'

NL : ('\n'|'\r\n');

// Unordered sections
INIFile:
    (RoutingSection) & (AnyOtherSection)

RoutingSection:
    (ROUTING_SECT_KW)(NL)* //=== tried to define keyword "Routing" here instead of data type rule, but 
                           //    results are same
    (key=KEY)'='(values+=VALUE)*(NL)*

AnyOtherSection:
    sectName=(SECTION)(NL)*
    ('KEY1=')(Value1=VALUE)?(NL)*
    ('KEY2=')(Value2=VALUE)?(NL)*
```

Above grammar works fine till we start to define a section name for "AnyOtherSection" with "Ro..."

So, the issue is that we have a keyword "Routing" and when we type only "Ro" for "AnyOtherSection" as "section" name, Xtext throws an error.

How can we resolve this matching keyword characters issue?

---

Worst case solution, i found is that,
If we have to include all possible keywords like 'Ro','Rou', 'Rout'...'Routin' in "SECTION" data type rule, the above sample ini file will be parsed without any errors but issue is that it will create more keywords in grammar file which will take more memory & time to compile (Generating artifacts).Also, in future, some other standard section to be added, then it will become more complex with keywords.

---

Please note that "Routing" section is a Standard section name that accepts any key-value parameters except the standard keys "KEY1, KEY2" and on the other hand "AnyOtherSection" section accepts any Alphanumeric value as "section" name but the "key" parameters are standard one (KEY1, KEY2).

I hope the above content are understandable way.

Comment: what about just using one rule for all sections and move the routing / `@` thingy to semantic validation?

Comment: or you can try if configuring lexer backtracking helps `parserGenerator = { options = { backtrackLexer = true } }` (am not sure if this is a good idea)

Comment: Hi CD, Thanks for your suggestions above. I tried what you have mentioned in first comment and when we use one rule for all section, then Xtext doesn't differentiate the 'Routing' & 'Other' sections. For 'Routing' section, it says standard keys 'KEY1' & 'KEY2' are missing. And as per your second comment, I have to try it. I am sorry about asking this what this "Lexer Backtracking" does and what are the effects?

Comment: i dont know if it has negative side effects. this is why i ask you to try.
and of course if you have one rule you need to support all key possibilities for all sections and then validate bad ones out

Comment: Hi, Checked with "backtrackLexer" option and... works fine with matching section name characters and it has created new issues too... such as "Unordered Groups" are not working. For Example: If we write "Rest"/"Rosy"... sections first and then "Routing", Xtext throws an error for "Routing" section that "KEY1" & "KEY2" (Standard keys) are missing. I believe, "AnyOtherSection" rule trying to consume "Routing" section as well. Any more suggestions?

Comment: unfortunately not